# Update TodoTask in the background

Tags: c#, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application whereby I keep track of activities. In order to synchronise these activities with Microsoft Outlook calendar, I am creating a TodoTask for each activity using the following piece of code:

```
public async Task<bool> AddCallToCalendar(ActivityModels.Call call)
    {
        var user = await _graphClient.Me.Request().Select("MailboxSettings").GetAsync();
        var userTimeZone = user.MailboxSettings.TimeZone;

        var todoTask = new TodoTask
        {
            DueDateTime = new DateTimeTimeZone
            {
                DateTime = call.Date.ToString("o"),
                TimeZone = userTimeZone,
                ODataType = null
            },
            
            IsReminderOn = true,
            ReminderDateTime = new DateTimeTimeZone
            {
                DateTime = call.Date.AddMinutes(-15.0).ToString("o"),
                TimeZone = userTimeZone,
                ODataType = null
            },

            Importance = GetImportance(call.Activity.Priority),

            Title = call.Activity.Subject,
            LinkedResources = new TodoTaskLinkedResourcesCollectionPage()
            {
                new LinkedResource
                {
                    WebUrl = $"https://example.com/activities/call/{call.Id}", 
                    ApplicationName = "Name",
                    DisplayName = "Name",
                    ODataType = null
                }
            },
            ODataType = null
        };

        var todoLists = await _graphClient.Me.Todo.Lists.Request().GetAsync();

        var defaultList = todoLists.Where(x => x.WellknownListName == WellknownListName.DefaultList).First();

        try
        {
            await _graphClient.Me.Todo.Lists[defaultList.Id].Tasks.Request().AddAsync(todoTask);

            return true;
        }

        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The above code works fine, but my challenge is how to update this TodoTask. I'd like to do the update in the background since it is possible that the current logged in user has a large number of TodoTasks and searching through them may affect performance. I am aware that Application Permission is currently not supported for Task.ReadWrite which would have made it possible to search and update TodoTasks in the background. Does anyone have an idea how to go about this?

Thank you in anticipation of your brilliant ideas / suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in order to create daemon application or background process you need to have Application permission (specific to your scenario). Unfortunately it's not available at this point and i don't see any other workaround either. So i would suggest you to consider filing uservoice with Microsoft or [better upvoting the existing one](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41509036-application-permissions-for-todo-api), so that they can implement it.